# Which types prevent Visual Studio visualizers showing?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, debuggervisualizer

I have found that certain types when present in `DebuggerVisualizerAttribute` prevent showing **all** visualizers. Not only the one in which they are present but all with exception of the most generic ones (Text, XML, JSON, HTML). Even the DataTable visualizer is blocked. So far I have identified `SortedList<int,string>`, `DataRow[]` (array of Datarow) and many others.

I need **to exclude** those types from generated list of types (for visualizing an interface). I did not managed to get any error message (debugging output, ActivityLog.xml, debugging the Visual Studio with other instance of it, WinDbg was not tested).

## Steps to reproduce the behavior

I use VS2017,.NET 4.7.1, W 10 x64 EN (I didn't notice the problem on VS2012,.NET 4.5 W 7, but it was reproduced in VS2015)

1. Create a debugger visualizer for string and test it (For example
   [Walkthrough: Writing a Visualizer in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-writing-a-visualizer-in-csharp?view=vs-2017), [Walkthrough: Writing
   a Visualizer in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-writing-a-visualizer-in-visual-basic?view=vs-2017) but probably any other visualizer
   will do)
2. Install the visualizer (copy to *My Documents\ VisualStudioVersion
   \Visualizers* - [How to: Install a Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2017))
3. Start debugging in Visual Studio and check that the created
   visualizer is offered (I recommed also checking presence of
   the magnifying glass for DataTable)
4. Add one of following attributes to the visualizer code:

```cs
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(MyFirstVisualizer.DebuggerSide), typeof(VisualizerObjectSource), Description = "Failing1",
        Target = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<int, string>))]
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(MyFirstVisualizer.DebuggerSide), typeof(VisualizerObjectSource), Description = "Failing2",
        Target = typeof(System.Data.DataRow[]))]
```

or vb.net

```
<Assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(GetType(MyFirstVisualizer.DebuggerSide), GetType(VisualizerObjectSource), Description:="Failing1",
       Target:=GetType(System.Collections.Generic.SortedList(Of Integer, String)))>
<Assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(GetType(MyFirstVisualizer.DebuggerSide), GetType(VisualizerObjectSource), Description:="Failing2",
       Target:=GetType(System.Data.DataRow()))>
```

5. Install modified visualizer and test that it is not offered and
   magifying glass for DataTable is missing (it is necessary to restart
   debugging but not the Visual Studio)

## Partial solution

I have noticed that most of problem types are [Constructed Generic Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#fundamentals_topic4) and I magaged get rid of the problem with excluding types with `.IsGenericType` and `.IsConstructedGenericType`.

I did not wrote the solution as an answer because `Dictionary<int,string>` does not cause the problem and  `DataRow[]` is not a Constructed Generic Type.

## Notes

- When Options > Debugger > General > Use Managed Compatibility Mode is
  ticked. The problem cannot be reproduced (txh Hans Passant).
- The question was edited to include less obscure types and a partial solution.
- I did not manage adding winforms reference to net standard dll so I used .Net Framework for creating visualizer in 1.
- The problem is now reported to Microsoft: [Certain types prevent showing all custom Debugger Visualizers](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/357701/certaing-types-prevent-showing-custom-debugger-vis.html)

Comment: Hmm, CimReadOnlyKeyedCollection is an abstract class, you'll never encounter it while debugging.  Concrete implementations of it have their members [CompilerGenerated] and [DebuggerHidden], that might have something to do with it. The debugger in VS2015 is quite troublesome, I personally heavily favor Tools > Options > Debugger > General > Use Managed Compatibility Mode ticked.

Comment: @HansPassant: Abstract class doesn't make a problem (I have just tested Stream). With "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" visualizers are visible. Thx for at least some workaround.